# Robot Framework Custom Library Imports using WITH NAME

Tags: python, robotframework

I have recently started using Robot Framework for my Automation Framework, using my existing python Libraries

```
*** Settings *** 
Library ../../lib/ServerAPI.py WITH NAME ServerAPI 

*** Test Cases *** 
[TC-001]-Registering a device with INVALID SUBSCRIBER name to the server
      ServerAPI.subscriber None
      ${resp} register device ${token} ${devid}
      LOG ${resp}
      Should Be Equal ${resp} ${True}`
```

Its not recognising the ServerAPI keyword name for the library, can anybody help me, what i'm missing here?

Comment: Seems that you miss more whitespaces. If you use space separated format, you need at least two spaces to separate statements (keywords, arguments) but I can see only one in your example.
Doc here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#plain-text-format

Comment: I tried with 2 spaces also, but its not recognising the name ServerAPI. Without WITH NAME, calling library functions directly are working fine.

Comment: Please show us the traceback.

Comment: I have only logs from testcase, not a complete stacktrace                                     `Register :: This is the register API testsuite                                
[TC-001]-Registering a device with INVALID SUBSCRIBER name to the ... | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'ServerAPI.subscriber' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Register :: This is the register API testsuite                        | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue resolved, it seems i was importing the .py file in my robot testcase, so WITH NAME it was not taking. I tried using the classname mentioned in the py file and added the path in PYTHONPATH, now its working. Thanks for all the suggestion

```
Library  ServerAPI  WITH NAME  serverApi
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in the question, it appears that you do not have the proper number of spaces before "WITH" and after "NAME" -- "WITH NAME" needs at least two spaces before and after (though, if you are using tabs, that may not be the problem).

For example:

```
*** Settings *** 
Library ../../lib/ServerAPI.py  WITH NAME  ServerAPI
```